# How to download photos (of others) from Instagram?

Tags: instagram

By *download*, I mean saving to SD card for later use. I have already explored the app for this option, but without luck. :(

I think, there must be a way to trap from cache.

If you've screenshot based suggestion, please don't answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a **rooted** device to do this.

- First Browse the photos you want to download.
- Now Open any File Explorer app like Root Explorer.
- Navigate to `/data/data/com.instagram.android/cache` via Root Explorer.
- The files here would be named something like `ccf3a266.0`, copy the file you
  want or entire folder and paste it on your sd card.
- Now open these `.0` files in your PC via a Image viewer like IrfanView. You can sort
  the files by size to determine large images.

The `.0` files are cahce files and some of these are essentially `JPG` image files and quality may depend upon your device I believe because it would download compressed image if the device screen/density is small. (That's just a theory).

Comment: *.0 files are not image files.. I've just tested opening a random file as image..

Comment: Sorry, I phrased it wrong, all of the `.0` won't be images. A lot of these would be cache file for other things too. But you should be able to sort the files by size and pick up the larger ones and try to open them up. I have tested this on my Samsung Galaxy 3 with CM9. (I side-loaded Instagram on my device. On Google play it says, not compatible).

Comment: Still, no luck.. I've opened every *.0 file as image. Instead, I got some image files (without extension) in `webviewCache` directory, but those are in super poor quality... not like what shown on device screen.

Comment: Hmm.. So maybe App is clearing cache every-time it's exiting. You can try viewing the image on Instagram, keep the image open & press Home button so that the app keeps running in background and cache doesn't get cleared. That's how I did it. :)

Comment: Using FolderSync, I've set to instant upload on that directory change. And, it worked.

Comment: @SachinShekhar Did you use Pro version? Or Lite?

Comment: @geff_chang I have Pro version. Why?

Comment: @SachinShekhar Can you see the folders inside /data using FolderSync? I can't. So I can't sync the folder for Instagram.

Comment: @geff Maybe, your device is blocking it. My device is Samsung Galaxy S which is open.

Comment: @SachinShekhar Weird. Because my Galaxy S2 has root, and I can see the contents of /data using a different file mananager (Astro).

Comment: @geff Then, contact developer..

Comment: @geff What I do: On choose local folder screen, I tap options button (top-right corner). Then, I choose change path which allows me to switch partitions. Try this before contacting developer.

Comment: @geff To switch partitions in File Manager of FolderSync, you can tap microSD icon at bottom bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you have ROOT access. This is a hassle free method if you don't want to go in system changing images extension.

1. Install [Xposed Framework](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer)
2. Install Framework by tapping "framework" item → Install/update
3. Install the module [XInsta](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ihelp101.instagram) or from app.
4. Activate module and reboot.
5. Open XInsta and update hooks by tapping "github" or "pastebin" item.
6. Kill (force-stop) Instagram.

Now, you will have a "Download" option in three dots in every image or video.
You can download every image and video by this method. If you use Easy Downloader app that will only let you download images of public accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the image using Instagram in the mobile browser:

1. Log into [Instagram](https://instagram.com/) in the mobile browser (like Chrome).
2. Click on the image you want.
3. Tap on the address bar at the top and add `view-source:` to the beginning of the URL (before the `https`).
4. Find a line in the code like: `<meta property="og:image" content="https://scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s480x480/e35/#############.jpg" />`
5. Copy the URL listed after `content="` between the quotes (long-press then drag the tags to mark the beginning (`https`) and end (`.jpg`) of the text to copy - do not copy the quotes).
6. Open a new tab and paste into the address bar or Google search box and press enter (NOTE: remove the `/s480x480` if you want the full-size image).
7. Long-press and save the image.

No root access required.