# Download or get the Instagram video I saw earlier

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, instagram

Device: Samsung Galaxy S3

A person I followed had a cool video they posted on Instagram, but then deleted it later. I was wondering if there was a backup of the video in the temp folder, since I watched it earlier?

Comment: See if the answer here helps: [How to download photos (of others) from Instagram?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22022/how-to-download-photos-of-others-from-instagram)

Answer (score 1):

The location of the Instagram cache is storage/android/data/com.instagram.android/cache/video 
However, when I look on my device, it seems that the files are not stored in a traditional video format. You should be able to find the video there, if at all though.

Answer (score 0):

`storage/android/data/com.instagram.android/cache/video/`

change the file extension from `.0` to `.mp4`