# How I look at the cache photos on instagram?

Tags: cache, instagram

[How to download photos (of others) from Instagram?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22022/how-to-download-photos-of-others-from-instagram)
I already saw this question but I can not see the files 0.'s is possible?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to copy the files with `.0` extension elsewhere on your device (*say* : to downloads folder) then rename them from `filename.0` to `filename.jpg`
they should open fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible by default.  If your device is rooted, you might be able to inspect your file system, and find where the pictures are stored (and then, you might be able to actually view them, depending on if there are encrypted).

Bottom line, I don't think Instagram wants you looking at their pictures, outside of their app, and you will need to bypass their controls to do this.

Comment: my device is root, and when I want see the files of instagram, files .0 appear, but if it can't see,  thanks anyway!

Comment: They have probably encrypted their imagery (since this is their biggest value proposition, and their 'product').  I don't think they want you looking at your pictures outside of the app.